# Is it possible to obtain the code from an anonymous function in PHP?

Tags: php, reflection, anonymous-function

Suppose I have an anonymous function:

```
$func = function() { return true; }
```

I want to (dynamically) obtain the string `"return true;"` from the variable `$func`.

Comment: Whatever you are doing with this, if it is not just for you. Stop it!

Comment: I think you are mixing PHP up with Javascript. The latter does indeed allow that. But PHP doesn't preserve the original body, just bytecode.

Comment: Reflection makes it possible to get the filename and line-numbers, so this isn't directly possible or very easy, but it is possible. The answer you're looking for is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25586109/view-a-php-closures-source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reflect such function:

```
$test = function() { return true; };

$r = new ReflectionFunction($test);
var_dump($r->getName());
```

However from what I can see in manual, PHP's reflection API doesn't provide any method that would return function's source. You can obtain start and end line of function declaration, what combined with such code-style:

```
$test = function() {
    return false;
}
```

Will let you quite easily obtain function's source. But remember that this is very tricky and as @Col. Shrapnel and @DampeS8N mentioned: *you really don't want to do that*.

Comment: Thanks for at least answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. The code is parsed and no string representation exists.

Comment: Of course it does - in the source file. The only exception would be functions you've created using `create_function()` or `eval()`, but if you declared a closure (as in the example in the question) while there may not be source-code in memory, there is of course source-code behind it, in the file that declared the function. `ReflectionFunction` includes `getFileName()`, `getStartLine()` and `getEndLine()`, so it's complicated, but it is possible to get the source-code.